# HTML form action to execute cgi is not working

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I have been trying to run a simple perl-cgi script on windows XP. This is a simple HTML form with an Submit button where clicking on Submit button displays some text(Username). But clicking the Submit button on the HTML page, nothing is happening. If I open up browser with url its working fine.

**HTML Form:**

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="C:/Server/Apache2/cgi-bin/hello.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1><center>User Login</center></h1>

<p><label><h4>Username</h4></label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></p>

<p><label><h4>Password</h4></label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></p>

<button type="submit">Sign-In</button><br><br>
```

**CGI :**

```
 #!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe -wT

    local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
    # Read in text
    $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
    if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
    {
        read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    }else {
        $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
    }
    # Split information into name/value pairs
    @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
    foreach $pair (@pairs)
    {
        ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
        $FORM{$name} = $value;
    }
    $user_name = $FORM{username};


print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h2>Hello $user_name - Second CGI Program</h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";

1;
```

**Opening CGI directly in browser:**

[image]

Comment: What did apache say to the error log?

Comment: @choroba: There is no error in logs.But I found one more thing. If I use 'action="/cgi-bin/hello.cgi"'in my html form as my httpd.conf has alias `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Server/Apache2/cgi-bin/"`, by clicking on submit button a page opens up with url `C:\cgi-bin\hello.cgi`. But it should be `C:/Server/Apache2/cgi-bin/hello.cgi`

Answer (score 1):

You need proper URL in form `action` attribute, ie. `action="/cgi-bin/hello.cgi"`

Comment: If I use `action="/cgi-bin/hello.cgi"`in my html by clicking on submit button a page opens up with url `C:\cgi-bin\hello.cgi`

Comment: what is url of your html form?

Comment: I changed the `action` to `action=http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.cgi` and it started working. If I want to use any `.pl` file like `action=http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.pl`  should I edit my `httpd.conf` to `AddHandler cgi-script .pl` ??

Comment: That would be wise, but using absolute url in form action not so much. What would happen if you're coming to web form from another computer?

Comment: `action="/cgi-bin/hello.cgi"` and you didn't tell me what is url of your html form

Comment: If I use `action="/cgi-bin/hello.cgi"`in my html by clicking on submit button a page opens up with url `C:\cgi-bin\hello.cgi`..But the url is `C:/Server/Apache2/cgi-bin/hello.cgi`

Comment: That is not url of the form but of the script, and it's `http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.cgi`

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion just to add.

Since it looks like you are just starting to learn perl, I would read into the `CGI` module. CGI is a widely used perl module for programming `CGI : Common Gateway Interface` which is used to recieve `user input` and produce `HTML` output. It processes form submissions, query string manipulation, and processing and preparing HTTP headers.

There are two styles of programming with CGI, `object-oriented` and `function-oriented`.